# Multi-line git commit message with PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm

Is it possible? PyCharm provides a nice textbox for editing the commit message, but it ignores line breaks and all the text end up as a single long header line in git.

I sometimes want to have a short header and then explain more later in the body and be able to see a concise header with git log --oneline

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Could you, please, attach a screenshot, because I don't use PyCharm, but I do use RubyMine and PhpStorm (same family) and never experienced your problem before?

Comment: Thank you for your screenshot, could you also show `git log` output? Also, it seems you have 2 blank lines between your commit header and commit body, although it is recommended to have only one.

Comment: using intelliJ (from Jetbrains too) and using `git log` with `--abbrev-commit` option, seems to work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Pycharm doesn't ignore line breaks, it just tries to show a commit message single lined for quick visualization purposes in some places but if you take a look at the logs' commit details you will see that the line breaks are still there. Here is a screenshot of a multi-line commit viewed from the logs:

[image]

Comment: That's right. There must be an empty line between the header and the body. I got confused by auto-wrapping.